# mysql load data infile takes too long and db file grows too large

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import pretty large file (3.5G with 39mlm rows) with

```
set foreign_key_checks=0; 
set sql_log_bin=0; 
set unique_checks=0;
load data infile '/var/lib/mysql-files/2.csv' ignore 
into table main_data fields terminated by ','  
optionally enclosed by '"' 
lines terminated by '\n' 
ignore 1 rows (col, col2, col3);
```

It already passed like 24 hours, and database file in `/var/lib/mysql/MyDB` grow to 11G, I am not sure why, because the file I import from is less than 4G. 
It is mysql 8.0. The only things I added to config is

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 22G
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
```

I think if I batch insert these data it would be faster...

As suggester in 1st comment here is creat table syntax. 
I now think that so many indexes can be the issue with size and time :

```
CREATE TABLE `main_data` (
  `file_name` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `line_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `doc_type` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_keywords` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_description` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `language` varchar(5) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `done` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`file_name`,`line_number`),
  UNIQUE KEY `link_UNIQUE` (`link`),
  KEY `done_idx` (`done`),
  KEY `lang_idx` (`language`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I only import 1st three columns (file_name, line_number, link), rest are nulls.

Answer (score 1):

24 hours is a very long time- the most important factor when running `LOAD DATA` is the buffer pool, and yours (22GB) should be enough to accommodate the imported 3.5G file. Something else must be going on, please share more data like the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output for the used table and `SHOW PROCESSLIST`- maybe there is something blocking the table and you are waiting for the process to start. You can check at any time the state of the load by checking the `GLOBAL STATUS` for `innodb%' as well as the`Handler_writes`.

To give you an idea of how much I would expect this to take, a 3.7 GB file should not take much more than 200 seconds to safely load on an SSD desktop-grade machine. See these tests I did not a long time ago on all recent MariaDB and MySQL versions on a non-server grade machine, even on a default (bad) config: https://dbahire.com/testing-again-load-data-on-mysql-5-6-5-7-8-0-non-ga-and-mariadb-10-0-10-1-and-10-2-non-ga/

Comment: Hi thanks! It finished after 1 day and 18 minutes... I added create table, there were no other processes...

Comment: That is too too long, check your host io performance and memory metrics (e.g. swapping). Maybe you have enabled binary logging and that is what dragging down your performance. Check also your sys metrics to know what file is taking most of your io.

Answer (score 1):

A guess...  You are building two secondary indexes that have only one distinct value in them -- `NULL`.

`DROP` the indexes on `done` and `language`, do the `LOAD`, then re-`ADD` the indexes.

As for the other two indexes...  Both are unique, so both must be checked as each row is inserted.  However, since the buffer_pool is much bigger than the entire dataset and indexes, this check should be done entirely in RAM (in the buffer_pool).  That is, I agree that "minutes", not "a day", is what you should expect.

Is this `LOAD` a one-time task?  Will you be adding to the table?  Etc.  (I am fishing for the next problem you might encounter here.)

Comment: I think I will move these three  columns into separate table, drop all the indexes, and check speed again.  Brb hopefully in "minutes" :-)

Comment: it definitely helps!
I just created new table with these three fields removed unique index, and tried to load data into it, it's nearly speed of light now, compared to what it was. 
I also launched it with `service mysql restart --innodb-doublewrite=0` as some posts suggested. 
Done in 12 mins... same file.

Comment: @MikeKlemin - Great!.  A caution about turning off "doublewrite" -- Don't leave it off unless you have special hardware support.  It is your protection against a rare, but deadly, possible data corruption.  (cf "torn page".)

Comment: Indeed, it is ok for a one-time import, but not ok to disable it for normal operation.